# The scroll to bottom auto not work when use the code in function viewDidLoad in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am have the below code ,
when set this code in button it is work but i am need set the code in viewDidLoad but is not work,

```
let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

please advise about this.
thank you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to Move your Code in viewWillLayoutSubview or viewDidLayoutSubview . if not work then move to viewDidAppear.